# Background App Refresh says completion not called when accessing pedometer data

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build an app that counts steps, as well as other things, but I am having some issues with the background app refresh portion of it. My thought was, once an hour (or thereabout depending on how the system decides to run it) the app would run background app refresh which would query the pedometer data for the past hour (or however long it has been since the last query). The problem is every time I try to run the simulate background refresh I get the message that the completion function was never called. I have looked into this a lot and found some examples of the best way to handle background app refresh with completion functions and implemented, but it seems to fail every single time. I've simplified the code to hopefully make it easier.

In my AppDelegate...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Getting new steps")
        getNewSteps { (res) in
            print("Return from the getNewSteps")
            completionHandler((res) ? .newData : .noData)
        }
    }
```

Then my getNewSteps does some calculations on the date getting the last time the query was run and trying to query the new data...

```
func getNewSteps(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
  print("In getNewSteps")
  let lastQuery = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastQuery") as? Int64 ?? 0
  print("got last query date")
  var startQueryDate: Date!
  if lastQuery == 0 {
    let date = Date()
    var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
    components.hour = 0
    components.minute = 0
    components.second = 0
    startQueryDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
  } else {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month,. day], from: Date(milliseconds: lastQuery))
    startQueryDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
  }
  print("got startQueryDate")
  let pedometer = CMPedometer()
  pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: startQueryDate, to: Date()) { data, error -> Void in
    print("in the pedometer query")
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
      print("There was an error")
      completionHandler(false)
      return
    }
    if data.numberOfSteps.intValue > 0 {
      //add steps and save
      UserDefaults.standard.set(Date().millisecondsSince1970, forKey: "lastQuery")
      completionHandler(true)
    } else {
      completionHandler(false)
    }
  }
}
```

So I run the simulator and do the simulate background refresh and I get the print messages for everything, except the last thing I get is "got startQueryDate" then it immediately tells me the completion handler was never called. I don't even get the message that I am in then pedometer query.

Is there something wrong with my code, or is it just not possible to access the pedometer in the background through something like this. I have seen pages say that accessing that accelerometer data is impossible in the background, but I have seen others saying it's possible to access the pedometer in the background, so I am not sure if my code is bad, or if it's just not possible. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try calling `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` before retrieving the pedometer data to let iOS know that you are still working. Don't forget to end the background task when you are done.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure I know what that means, I thought the completion handler let the system know the background task was complete. Is there any way you could give me an example? Thank you